# javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named em1

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, glassfish

I am creating a server in Glassfish and I want to have a JPA persistence layer to a remote MySQL database.

When I attempt to use the persistence layer, I get this exception: `javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named em1`

Based on other StackOverflow posts, it seems this is an indication the persistence.xml is invalid. My persistence.xml is shown. Can someone point me in the right direction to figuring out how to get this to work?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
    <persistence-unit name ="em1">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>data.entry.Movie</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.target-database"
                      value="MySQL4"/>

            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="mysql3.cs.myschool.edu/mydb"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="mydb" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="mypass" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: can you do it with `transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"` after `name = "em1"`. Also  ` <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>`

Comment: Nope, added both of those and still getting the exception

Comment: Other things to look is make sure your persistence.xml is in `/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF`

Comment: A persistence.xml was automatically created by IntelliJ when setting up the project. It's in /src/main/java/META-INF. I tried placing it in the location you said but still not working

Comment: Looks right to me. You might want to try putting persistance.xml in resources/META-INF, in case you are using maven to build a jar? If you are running from jar make sure the persistence.xml is included and on the classpath (normally in META-INF).

Comment: What do you mean the classpath? Where is that? I notice that there is a .iml file and it contains a line that says `<deploymentDescriptor name="persistence.xml" url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/java/META-INF/persistence.xml" />` which is indeed where it is actually located

Comment: `mysql3.cs.myschool.edu/mydb` is not in a valid JDBC-URL format.